# How to fix image path for slider function

Tags: javascript

Function to slide banner not working and my image path not working too

```
var img = document.getElementById('img-banner');

var images = [
    '../banners/banner.png', 
    '../banners/banner1.png',
    '../banners/banner2.png'
];

var x = 0;

function slide() {

    if (x > images.length) {
        x++
    } else {
        x = 1;
    }

    img.innerHTML = "<img src ="+images[x-1]+">";
}

setInterval(slide, 5000);
```

Comment: Change the if condition to (x < images.length)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your x variable will always be equal to 1 since the code will never get inside the if statement. if(x > images.length) will never become true.

try if( x < images.length );

in image src, you are decrementing by 1 which results to show the zero index always. nothing wrong with your path.